# "TypeError: Tried to lookup Dir '...' as a File." in scons variant_dir build

Tags: scons

I'm working on a hierarchical multi-variant build with scons.  For a library called "lib" the generic source is under `src/lib` while the variant-specific source is under `src/lib/variant`.  (Example, `src/lib/linux` on Linux machines.)  If there is no variant-specific code for a particular variant, the directory may not exist.  When my setup uses the `Progress()` function to print out as each file is evaluated by scons, it throws a TypeError telling me `TypeError: Tried to lookup Dir 'src/lib/subdir_1' as a File.`

I have scons version 3.0.1-1 on Ubuntu.  My default python is 2.7.16.

I can't figure out exactly where I would be causing scons to create a File node for the non-existant directory `src/lib/subdir_1`, but for the error to reproduce, I do need to include `$TARGET` in the `Progress()` call.  Removing `src_subdirs` from the environment makes the error go away, as does only building a single variant.  Additionally, the `Glob()` function seems to be required to make the error reproduce, too.

My reproduction case has three files (and no actual source in this minimal example, just the scons files and the directories containing them):

SConstruct:

```
base_env = Environment()
Progress('Evaluating $TARGET\n')

env = base_env.Clone(src_subdirs = ['subdir_1'])
Export('env')
SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir = 'build/variant_1', duplicate = 0)

env = base_env.Clone(src_subdirs = ['subdir_2'])
Export('env')
SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir = 'build/variant_2', duplicate = 0)
```

src/SConscript:

```
SConscript(Glob('*/SConscript'))
```

src/lib/SConscript:

```
Import('env')

src = []
src_subdirs = env['src_subdirs']
for s in src_subdirs:
    src += env.Glob(s + '/*.c')
```

The full error message:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Evaluating SConstruct
Evaluating src/SConscript
Evaluating src/lib/SConscript
Evaluating build/variant_1/lib/subdir_1
Evaluating build/variant_1/lib
Evaluating build/variant_1
Evaluating src/SConscript
Evaluating src/lib/SConscript
scons: done building targets.
TypeError: Tried to lookup Dir 'src/lib/subdir_1' as a File.:
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1376:
    _exec_main(parser, values)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1339:
    _main(parser)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1103:
    nodes = _build_targets(fs, options, targets, target_top)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1313:
    jobs.run(postfunc = jobs_postfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 111:
    self.job.start()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 227:
    task.failed()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 271:
    nodename = ', '.join(map(str, node))
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 639:
    return self._save_str()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 652:
    result = SCons.Util.silent_intern(self._get_str())
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 660:
    srcnode = self.srcnode()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 742:
    srcnode.must_be_same(self.__class__)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 602:
    (self.__class__.__name__, self.get_internal_path(), klass.__name__))
```

As you can see, it has finished parsing my code at the time of the error.  Presumably something during the SConscript parsing created the problem situation, but since it doesn't point back to my code, I'm having trouble guessing how to fix it.

Comment: Does 'src/lib/subdir_1' exist?

Comment: Also try SCons 3.0.5 (simplest way is to create a virtualenv and install it in that)

Comment: @bdbaddog, src/lib exists, but src/lib/subdir_1 does not.  If I create it, the error does not occur, but the whole point is that they should be optional.

In my full example, I'm currently testing for directory existence before the Glob(), and that also seems to suppress the error, but if I ever had a reason for build/variant_1/lib/subdir_1 to exists but not src/lib/subdir_1, then it would, AIUI, have been seen by the Glob but not with my workaround.  (Though I don't anticipate that actually happening for this project.)

Comment: Okay, I tested with scons 3.0.5 and got the same behavior.

Comment: Can you make a small repo on github or other that we can download and reproduce this issue?

Comment: @bdbaddog Done.  [Here's a repo for you.](https://github.com/chrisdsloan/scons_repro_dir_as_file.git)

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. Please file an issue on github https://github.com/SCons/scons/issues  and link to this SO question and your repo?